# How can I turn off my server when i am in the login screen?

Tags: server, login-screen

I would like to turn off my server by pressing the power button. The problem is if I am in the login screen (I haven't logged in yet). Pressing the power button will not shutdown my server. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: **DO NOT DO WHAT @Sam IS SUGGESTING HERE.** You will very likely corrupt your filesystem and **lose data irrecoverably** if you make a habit of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install acpid`

That should be all you need to do; after that, the server will catch the ACPI event caused by a short power button press and respond by shutting down cleanly.